# Unordered pattern/rule matching(?) with 'OR' capability on a PostgreSQL array field

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, search, pattern-matching

### Abstract

I'm writing code for a data analysis tool that interfaces with a **PostgreSQL** database and constructs an SQL query to filter to a set of rows based on user input. In broad terms, each row is a record containing a set of input data and an associated output/result. The utility I'm developing allows users to see different views of this data by applying filters to the input and output values.

There's a field in this table which contains an **array of integers** which represent the 'classes' of a set of entities, which is part of the 'input'. These classes have the most direct impact upon the output, so the particular assortment of values in this field is of particular importance to users of the system. There are twenty unique 'class' values, and the array typically has no more than six elements. There can, in certain circumstances, be two such arrays in a single record, and they may be queried either separately, or combined together into a single set of up to 12 values.

My system provides a freeform input where users can write filter criteria specifically to filter results based on the contents of this field. It allows the user to specify a list of class designations they wish to include in the filter clause, as well as any they wish to explicitly exclude. The grammar of this freeform input is based upon a preexisting community-defined syntax used outside this system to represent the data in question, and adapted here for the purpose of filtering.

Multiple entities in a given record may have the same 'class', so the same values can appear multiple times in the array, and the user can specify a constraint on the number of instances of each class value. The length of this array can also vary, but the user may only be interested in specific items, so the user may specify wildcards and place constraints upon the length of the array.

The arrays are unsorted, as the particular order (most notably, the value in the first position) can occasionally be of importance.

### Examples

The data as stored in the database column is an array of integers, but for demonstration purposes, I will use textual class designations in the following example. Users input these textual designations in their queries, which are then translated by the system to numeric IDs.

Example field data: `[A, B, B, E, B, D]`

Example user inputs which would successfully match the above:

`A B B B D E` // Explicitly written, filters to rows matching this exact list of items. Order doesn't matter *unless* the user also selects an option to match the first entry explicitly.

`6*` // Array wildcard with length constraint; filters to any rows with an array length of 6.

`2-3B *` // Filters to any rows containing between two and three (inclusive) instances of B, and zero or more other non-B items (unconstrained array wildcard *).

`A 2B 3XX` // Filters to any rows containing at least one A, two B, and exactly three other items (class wildcard XX) of any class (which may *also* be A and/or B)

All of this currently works. My *current* method is to determine the potential upper/lower bounds of the instance counts (or lack thereof) of all specified classes, as well as that of the array length itself, and construct a query that checks those instance counts and array lengths and returns rows which successfully meet those criteria.

### The problem...

All of the current syntax works great at the moment. It is purely of "AND" fashion, however -- and the #1 requested feature for this system is the introduction of an "OR" syntax, which is commonly used within the community to denote when certain sets of classes are considered interchangeable.

For example:

`A B|C` would match both `[A,B]` and `[A,C]`.

`3(B|C)` would match `[B,B,B]`, `[C,C,C]`, `[B,C,B]`, etc..

These kinds of queries are often more complex, with things like `2(A|B) 2(B|C|D) 2E` not being uncommon. This potential for increasing complexity is where my brain starts to break down when trying to find a solution.

I believe that my current solution of tracking expected instance counts for each value is not inherently compatible with this (unless I'm simply overcomplicating things or overlooking something), but I have been at a loss for how better to approach it, made worse by the fact that I don't know what this type of issue is even called. I believe it would be considered a form of unordered pattern/rule matching, but that's quite a broad umbrella and my searches thus far have been fruitless.

I'm not really looking to be spoonfed a solution, but if there's anyone who recognizes the sort of problem I'm dealing with and has an idea of what topics I could research to figure it out on my own (particularly in the context of SQL queries), it would be immensely helpful.

#### Database notes

The data pool that a typical query is performed upon is a 30-day period with a subset of data spanning, on average, about 300,000 rows. This window can be increased, and it's not especially uncommon for users to perform long-term queries spanning many millions of rows. Performance is pretty important.

The SQL database in question is a replica of an external partner's database. It is replicated periodically via a binary copy operation, and thus the original format of the tables is largely maintained. Additional fields may be added to optimize access to certain types of data, but this must be done in a separate step during the replication process, and I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Hi Planerarian, your problem/solution looks like the regular expression, and it seems that you try to reinvent the wheel ... You can read carefully this : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP . In your case, you just have to convert your array into a text with the array_to_string() function and then you can use the regular expressions which are very powerful. Hope this will help.

Comment: For only 20 elements: don't us an array. You could optimise later.

Comment: @wildplasser There are 20 possible element values; each array field has typically no more than 6 elements (but there are cases where a row may have two sets of these and they can be queried together as a 12-value set). Also, the database itself is a replica of a third-party database; I can introduce new fields and converted versions of existing fields, but it must be performed as part of the replication process. I was hoping to keep as close to the original format as possible (as any changes will involve updating the millions of backdated records) but converting isn't out of the question.

Comment: @EdouardH. I had considered regular expressions for this, but the unordered nature of the data/queries made it seem impractical; I'm not really a regex pro, though. I will do some research and see how this can be accomplished with regex.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as stated is very similar to regular expressions even if the unordered nature of the queries makes regular expressions not fully suitable. But this can be solved by defining an `AGGREGATE` function which relies on regular expressions.
Considering that :

- Your arrays of integers to be evaluated may be converted as a text starting with '{', ending with '}' and with ',' as separator
- Your queries may be converted as a text and which is a set of elements with a space as separator. Each element is a regular expression of any kind, and especially : an element may be a simple numeric string which represents an integer, an element may be like '(A|B|C)' where A, B, C are numeric stings so that to implement the 'OR' operator between these integers, etc
- Your queries may be either ordered or non-ordered : ordered means that the array of integers is evaluated according to the order of the elements in the query, non-ordered means that the array of elements is evaluating againts every element of the query without any order consideration between these elements
- Your queries may be strict or non-strict : strict means that the array of integers exactly match the set of elements in the query, ie no additional integer exists in the array which doesn't match with the query elements, non-strict means that the array of integers may include some integers which do not match with any element of the query
- The ordered and strict parameters of the query are independent one from the other, ie the users may need ordered and non-strict queries, or non-ordered and strict queries, etc

the function `check_function` as defined here below should cover most of your use cases including the 'OR' syntax :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deduct
( str1 text
, str2 text
, reg text
) RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN res = COALESCE(str1,str2)
             THEN NULL
             ELSE res
           END
      FROM regexp_replace( COALESCE(str1,str2)
                         , reg
                         , ','
                         ) AS res
$$ ;

DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS deduct_agg(text, text);
CREATE AGGREGATE deduct_agg
( str text
, reg text
)
( sfunc = deduct
, stype = text
) ;

-- this function returns true when init_string matches with the reg_string expression according to the parameters ordered_match and strict_match
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_function
( init_string text      -- string to be checked against the reg_string; in case of an array of integer, it must be converted into text before being passed to the function
, reg_string text       -- set of elements separated by a space and individually used for checking the init_string iteratively
, ordered_match boolean -- true = the order of the elements in reg_string must be respected in init_string, false = every element in reg_string is individually checked in init_string without any matching order in init_string
, strict_match boolean  -- true = the init_string mut exactly match the reg_string, false = the init_string must match all the elements of the reg_string but with some extra substrings which don't match
) RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
DECLARE res boolean ;
BEGIN
    CASE
    WHEN ordered_match AND strict_match
    THEN SELECT deduct_agg(init_string, '(,|{)' || r.reg || '(,|})$' ORDER BY r.id DESC) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ','
           INTO res
           FROM regexp_split_to_table(reg_string,' ') WITH ORDINALITY AS r(reg,id) ;
    WHEN NOT ordered_match AND strict_match
    THEN SELECT deduct_agg(init_string, '(,|{)' || r.reg || '(,|})') IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ','
           INTO res
           FROM regexp_split_to_table(reg_string,' ') AS r(reg) ;
    WHEN ordered_match AND NOT strict_match
    THEN SELECT deduct_agg(init_string, '(,|{)' || r.reg || '(,|})') IS DISTINCT FROM NULL
           INTO res
           FROM regexp_replace(reg_string,' ', '.*','g') AS r(reg) ;
    ELSE SELECT deduct_agg(init_string, '(,|{)' || r.reg || '(,|})') IS DISTINCT FROM NULL
           INTO res
           FROM regexp_split_to_table(reg_string,' ') AS r(reg) ;
    END CASE ;
    RETURN res ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

The following use cases should be supported :

- "A B B B D E // Explicitly written, filters to rows matching this
  exact list of items. Order doesn't matter" ==> implemented as `SELECT check_function(your_array_of_integers :: text, 'A B B B D E', true, true)`
- "6* // Array wildcard with length constraint; filters to any rows with an array length of 6." ==> implemented as `SELECT check_function(your_array_of_integers :: text,'([0-9]+,){5}([0-9]+)',true,true)`. This use case can be generalized by replacing "6*" by "n*" and `'{5}'` by `'{' || n-1 || '}'` in the reg_string, where n is any integer > 1
- "A 3B" with any order and strict ==> implemented as `SELECT check_function(your_array_of_integers :: text, 'A B B B', false, true)`
- "A (B|C)" with no order and not strict ==> implemented as `SELECT check_function(your_array_of_integers :: text, 'A (B|C)', false, false)`
- "3(B|C)" with no order and strict ==> implemented as `SELECT check_function(your_array_of_integers :: text, '(B|C) (B|C) (B|C)', false, true)`
- "2(A|B) 2(B|C|D) 2E" with no order and not strict ==> implemented as `SELECT check_function(your_array_of_integers :: text, '(A|B) (A|B) (B|C|D) (B|C|D) E E', false, false)`
- etc

The use cases which are not yet implemented :

- "2-3B" but some additional home work could make it happen, I don't see any blocking point. One idea would be to call the function check_function twice : `SELECT check_function (..., 'B B', ..., ...) AND NOT check_function (..., 'B B B B', ..., ...)`
- "2-3B *" and "A 2B 3XX" because the wildcards * and XX are not clear to me in that cases.

PS : I'm a basic user of regular expressions as I don't use all the capabilities as presented in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). Having the advices of an experienced user in regular expression could bring a lot of value in your context.

Comment: I will dig into this solution in some more detail when i have some more time, but just to answer a few points:
by default, queries are executed "as written", so `2A B` will enforce that the array *only* contains some permutation of `[A,A,B]`. The `*` character is an array wildcard that is equivalent to "...and any other elements". So, `2A B *` would match `[A,A,B,A]`, `[A,D,A,B,C]`, and so on. The `XX` syntax is an element wildcard that is equivalent to "any other element". So, "2A XX" would match `[A,A,A]`, `[A,A,B]`, and so on.

Comment: Both wildcards can be prefixed, but their prefixes have different meanings. `2A B 6*` means "two A and one B, and any other elements (which may also be A and/or B), with a total array length of 6". `2A B 2XX` means "two A and one B, and exactly two other elements (which may also be A and/or B)"

Comment: also worth noting, I suppose, that the `*` wildcard can also match zero elements. `[B,A,A]` will match for both `2A B` and `2A B *`.